# Solution Indication - Database

Tags: database, full-text-search, innodb, partitioning, myisam

I have a database with more than 2 million records and new records are made every day.

I'm using MySQL and I need fulltext, so I can't do partitioning, as it's not possible to use fulltext in a partitioned table.

Some queries are quick, but others are extremely time-consuming.
I would like a suggested solution for this.

Would it be worth switching to another type of database? which?

Thank you very much in advance, have a great day.

Comment: What problem are you encountering with InnoDB + FULLTEXT + millions of rows (and no partitioning)?  Let's see some examples of the slow queries.